# access client side variable (vbscript) in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, dom, datagrid, vbscript

I inherited a legacy app that is a mix of technologies from the last 10 yrs. It is not architected well so please don't berate me on why i need to do this, i just need to do it and get it done...

i have an important variable that is available client side in vbscript
i have an asp.net itemtemplate that lives inside a datagrid
i need to modify the style of a column in the grid based on the client variable
i cannot access the .net stuff in the vbscript to mess with it

i am trying to dynamically add a hidden field via vbscript to the page with the variable that i need, then find that in the .net code maybe using Page.FindControl so I can set the style dynamically using the variable that was given to me client side

any thoughts on the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Write the variable to a text file, read the text file into your .Net app.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, i sent the value in a query string and pulled it out using response.querystring on the .net side

the html tag itself has a .net function embedded in the class tag which will return the right style based on the value. the style hides the field

Comment: just a reminder to encrypt the query string if the information is sensitive and have some sort of check to make sure the string hasn't been compromised